# Crashing Reasons application c

Tags: c, windows, labwindows

Hi guys I have a big project written in C that sometimes (not always) in some condition crash.
This application read some measures from an eletronic board and store it to a log file in hard disk.
(The application is written with labwindows).
I created a dump file and this is what I obtained, I don't know what happen

```
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 12624

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 12617

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 358

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 47127

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 116

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 1182800

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 229618

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 5.10.0.0


NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  000033b4

PROCESS_NAME:  MyApplication.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {ERRORE DI EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint    stato raggiunto un breakpoint.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`0009e5b8 00007ff9`52674cb0     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00007ff9`00000003 : wow64win!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x14
00000000`0009e5c0 00007ff9`5270902a     : 00000000`0033d000 00007ff9`52674c20 00000000`0033f000 00000000`0033d000 : wow64win!whNtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x90
00000000`0009e620 00000000`773917c3     : 00000023`75fb101c 00007ff9`52700023 00000000`00000000 00000000`010ff654 : wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x15a
00000000`0009eee0 00000000`773911b9     : 00000000`010ffd24 00007ff9`527039b4 00000000`0009efb0 00007ff9`52703aaf : wow64cpu!ServiceNoTurbo+0xb
00000000`0009ef90 00007ff9`527038c9     : 00000000`0033c000 00000000`00400080 00000000`00000000 00000000`0009f800 : wow64cpu!BTCpuSimulate+0x9
00000000`0009efd0 00007ff9`527032bd     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`001b2298 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : wow64!RunCpuSimulation+0xd
00000000`0009f000 00007ff9`53c0351e     : 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000010 00007ff9`53c61770 00000000`0033b000 : wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x12d
00000000`0009f2b0 00007ff9`53bf2197     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x193e
00000000`0009f6e0 00007ff9`53ba4623     : 00000000`00000000 00007ff9`53b30000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0033d000 : ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x4db5b
00000000`0009f780 00007ff9`53ba45ce     : 00000000`0009f800 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x3b
00000000`0009f7b0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe


SYMBOL_NAME:  wow64win!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+14

MODULE_NAME: wow64win

IMAGE_NAME:  wow64win.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_wow64win.dll!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.388

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {30ec1d4c-7914-59db-81ea-e2f4fcb6fdf7}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: It's going to be fairly difficult to diagnose this issue without providing any actual code

Comment: "...sometimes (not always) in some condition crash.." You have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere in your program, and without a [mre] is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Start looking for any kind of patterns when the crash happens. For example, does it always happen for some specific input? If it does then it's easy to use a debugger to catch the crash and see when and where in your code it happens. If there doesn't seem to be a pattern, look for uninitialized variable (especially pointer) usage, or possible null-pointer access, and access arrays or dynamically allocated memory out of bounds.

Comment: You've got a minidump of the wow64 emulator, not of the failing 32-bit process.  It won't tell you anything interesting, use a 32-bit utility to create the minidump.